# How to get custom information from UserProfile?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, nullreferenceexception

I add in my *UserProfile* the custom field *UserType* as string. I want to change my `login post method to get the value from UserType` and pass this value in a TempData.

This is my code on AccountController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            var context = new UsersContext();
            var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
            string username = currentUser.UserName;
            var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            var userType = user.UserType;

            TempData["UserType"] = user.UserName; //Taking UserType from User Profile to validate in _Layout
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model); 
    }
```

I do a debug on this method, this is the informations that i have:

```
> **On WebSecurity.Login()** I can see the UserName and Password.
> **Var CurrentUser**  I can't get the value from User.Identity.Name
> **string Username** This error is displayed *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*. Application crash.
```

Anybody have some solution for this?
I'm new on ASP.NET, but maybe if I implements custom membership it will work, what do you think? Could you send me some example? Thank you guys.

Solution here:

`[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            var context = new UsersContext();
            var user = context.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserName == model.UserName);
            var userType = user.Select(m => m.UserType);

```
        TempData["UserType"] = user.UserName; //Taking UserType from User Profile to validate in _Layout
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model); 
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an Idea for in case I cannot Comment bcoz of my reputation, 
why are you not directly using `model.UserName` instead of using `var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);`

The Reason behind this is any one who logins will be the current user it self and you can retrieve its details form the database.

Updated

You Can Use

```
UserProfile User = udb.UserProfiles.Where(m => m.UserName == model.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
var userType=User.UserType; // this brings your UserType from database

// then you can use this as
TempData["UserType"]=userType;
```

Hopes this helps You !

Comment: Thank you @Kumar, I'll write it and post a comment if it works or not

Comment: Hi @Kumar your solution works for me, thanks for your answer!I'll update the post with my code.